# What do square brackets followed by exclamation mark in a linux command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, command

I found the following linux command.

```
 cp -f [!r][!e][!d][!m][!i][!n][!e]* /SomePath
```

I know what `cp` does and the `-f` is also no problem. But what I don;t know is what the square brackets and the exclamation marks do (`[!r]`, `[!e]`, `[!d]`, `[!m]`, `[!i]`, `[!n]`). Can anyone help me?

I found this command here: https://redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Migrate_Redmine_to_a_new_server_to_a_new_Redmine_version

Comment: [wildcards documentation](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) may be useful. Looks like it's copying everything except files with names that start with `redmine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in the manual under [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

> `[…]`
>   Matches any of the enclosed characters. [...] If the first character following the `[` is a `!` or a `^` then any character not enclosed is matched.

So, `[!r]` is any character except `r`, `[!e]` is any character except `e`, and so on. `[!r][!e][!d][!m][!i][!n][!e]*` expands to the names of all files that don't begin with the string `redmine` (except those that begin with `.`, unless the `dotglob` shell option is set).

There is another shell option that lets you write the same thing a little more elegant:

```sh
shopt -s extglob
cp -f !(redmine)* /SomePath
```

where `!(pattern)` matches everything except *`pattern`*.